# Try to use in malloc (c)

Tags: c

I try to create `arr[N][N]` and I wrote this:

```
int **arr;
arr = (int**)malloc((strlen(str) - 1) * sizeof(int*));
for (i = 0; i < strlen(str) - 1; i++) {
    arr[i] = (int*)malloc((strlen(str) - 1) * sizeof(int));
}
```

If in to example the size of str is 6 I need to create `arr[5][5]`, how can I fix it?

Comment: What problem are you facing? Also, in the first malloc, `int*` should be replaced with `int`.

Comment: What's wrong with this except `malloc` casting?

Comment: Do you really want the width and length if you 2D array to be the same?

Comment: I think maybe you want the size of the array to be `strlen(str)` and not `strlen(str) - 1`, but otherwise the code looks correct. What problem is it giving you?

Comment: Why is arr an int** instead of a void** ?

Comment: the problem is that when I try to get the arr[0][20] in to example its work,the arr isn't in the size that I want

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't you just do this (N could be 5):

```
int **arr;
arr = malloc(N*sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    arr[i] = malloc(N*sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: Removed casts from `malloc` calls... in C, `malloc`'s returned pointer shouldn't be cast, at least not in this case

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, yes your quite right, good discussion here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc.  Thanks.

Comment: I got error in the line arr = malloc( N * sizeof(int*) );
thanks

Comment: @user2976686, Don't forget to include the standard library, which contains malloc. So above main() you should have: #include <stdlib.h>

Comment: @roybatty,yes I include it

Answer (score 1):

Use `N` rather than `strlen(str) - 1`.

```
int **arr;
arr = malloc(N * sizeof(*arr));
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    arr[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(arr[i][0]));
}
```

Usually when `strlen(str)` comes into play, that allocation size is `strlen(str) + 1` (in the for loop only).

---

From subsequent comments, there is some confusion.  Now I assume OP wants to store an array of strings.   Assume there are up to `N` strings.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
char **arr;
// See note on casting the results of malloc()
arr = (char **) malloc(N * sizeof(*arr));
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  char str[100];
  scanf("%99s", str);
  size_t siz = strlen(str) + 1;
  arr[i] = (char *) malloc(siz);
  memcpy(arr[i], buf, siz);
}
```

Checking the results of `malloc()` is a good idea for robust code as in

```
arr = (char **) malloc(N * sizeof(*arr));
if (arr == NULL) handle_error();  // maybe exit?
```

Casting note: OP reports twice problems with code that uses a cast-less `malloc()`.  Not having the cast, with compliant compilers it should not be a problem.  But if OP is using a C++ compiler or something non-compliant, casting should fix that issue.  With modern C, casting `malloc()` results it is tolerable, but frowned upon.

Comment: Why have this in the loop: `N * sizeof(arr[i][0])`?  Seems like a waste of CPU cycles to recalculate it every loop iteration.

Comment: @Bit Fiddling Code Monkey I take it you are suggesting to create the `size_t len = N * sizeof(arr[i][0]);` before the loop and use `arr[i] = malloc(len);` inside the loop.  Should `N` be a constant, the posted code I'd expect a bit faster.  Should `N` be a variable, your idea would be faster.  In either case, profiling would provide definite results.  I'd expect margin differences.

Comment: hi,first thanks!..this is write me error in the line: arr = malloc(N * sizeof(*arr));